# How to import when I have spaces in file name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file name which

`Allan Munger.png`

How can I import it in Javascript?

I tried this but it says file not found

```
import AllanMunger from "./images/avatars/Allan Munger.png";
```

Where my index ts path is

```
src/assests/images/index.ts
```

And image path is

```
src/assests/images/avatars/Allan Munger.png
```

[image]

#### Update:

I have changes path from `images/` to `./images/`and types for .png file. White Ts doesn't throw error, React-native app does

[image]

[image]

#### Update 2

Fixed paths, still the same error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried escaping the space?

Comment: Actually for me both `'./test file'` and `'./test\ file'` work. Are you sure you've setup your bundler (probably webpack) so it can deal with files other than javascript and typescript? Can you try importing a `.png` that doesn't contain spaces?

Comment: @Elias I didn't have png type in typescript. I added type and everything works fine

Comment: Glat to hear 

Comment: @Elias unfortunately, it still not working

Comment: Can you show me how you are displaying the PNGs?

Comment: try "./avatars/Allan Munger.png";

Comment: you have index.ts and avatar folder both inside images so no need to add /images in import path.

Comment: Try `Allan\sMunger.png` or `Allan%20Munger.png`

Comment: @Elias can you please see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248916/react-native-bundler-weird-error-and-images-not-working/69248946#69248946

Comment: @JS_INF didn't make a difference but thanks for answering. new question for same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248916/react-native-bundler-weird-error-and-images-not-working/69248946#69248946

Comment: @DibashSapkota That was indeed an error on my end but that still didn't fix it. Thanks for pointing out though :). I have asked a new question for the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248916/react-native-bundler-weird-error-and-images-not-working/69248946#69248946