# react-native images with space in name not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to use an image in my react native app.

I have very little code at this point

This is all the code I have for now

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Image from '@src/assests/images/avatars/Allan Munger.png';
import { ImageCircle } from '@src/components/elements';

const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <View>
      <ImageCircle uri={Image} active={false} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Where ImageCircle is this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, ImageSourcePropType } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './styles';

const ImageCircle = ({ active, uri }) => {
  console.log('uri', uri);
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        borderRadius: 30,
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: 1,
      }}>
      <Image source={uri} width={60} height={60} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ImageCircle;
```

I can't see my image in the circle (or anywhere).

In the console, there is this one log

```
Asset not found: /Users/varunb/Desktop/project-emma/src/assests/images/avatars/Allan%20Munger@2x.png for platform: ios
```

Can someone tell me why I can't see the image on my iPhone and why am I getting this error? and how to fix it?

Ps: If I remove space from image import (and rename image as well), then everything works fine i.e

```
import Image from '@src/assests/images/avatars/AllanMunger.png';
```

This is what I can see on iPhone (with spaces in import)
[image]

Comment: It looks like this could be a bug. Is there anything preventing you from using `Allan_Munger.png` for the filename? Other than that I would recommend looking at the library code of react-native and opening an issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/facebook/react-native).

Comment: @Elias it's more like a coding assignment. I am not sure but it could be that this is intentional and my goal is to find a fix for this

Comment: I would go talk to the assigner about it. I just tested paths with spaces in my local environment and face the exact same issue as you.

Comment: Well, good on you for trying to fix it with your PR https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/705

I guess this confirms that it is a bug and there's not much we can do about it in the short term

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helping you

wrong format:

```
<Image source={uri} width={60} height={60} />
```

There are two kind of render Image style

```
<Image  style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
      />
<Image  style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }}
      />
```

In your case

```
<Image source = {{uri: uri} width: {60} height:{60}}
```

If you still not render image, you can use FastImage instead using Image

After npm install react-native-fast-image , you can use FastImage

Please check this url https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

It could be correctly working

Comment: Not accurate. I am not loading images from an external source. Also, I have updated my question. Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: I changed my answer, please check

Comment: Thanks again. The code snippet in your answer aren't working and I don't want to use fast-image.

Comment: FastImage ist definitely not required.

Comment: Ah infact this is incorrect. @ViktorM They are asking specifically about a path with spaces in it. Yours does not contain any.

Comment: @Elias Precisely. I am glad Viktor spent his time answering and debugging my problem but I did already mention that I am able to make it work without spaces.